# Migrate repository description from bonobo git server 4.x to 5.x

Tags: git, iis, windows-server, bonobo

Did somebody ever tried to migrate from Bonobo Git 4.x to 5.x?

I cannot migrate repository description from bonobo git server 4.x to 5.x.
There is no information about where do the descriptions of all projects stored in.

Of course I can transfer it manually, but it won’t help me because I’ve got more than 40 repositories.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that we use MembershipService Active Directory. In the new version it uses its own storage in the folder ~\App_Data\ADBackend\Repos as JSON files. In the previous version it used SQLite database. And we have no idea how to transfer data from old format to new one lossless.

Answer (score 1):

The only reference on to update the server are those few lines:
https://bonobogitserver.com/update/

> ***Update***
>   Before each update please read carefully the information about compatibility issues between your version and the latest one in changelog.
>
> - Delete all the files in the installation folder except App_Data.
> - Default location is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server.
> - Copy the files from the downloaded archive to the server location.
> - Review the migration notes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we use MembershipService Active Directory. In the new version it uses its own storage in the folder ~\App_Data\ADBackend\Repos as JSON files. In the previous version it used SQLite database. And we have no idea how to transfer data from old format to new one lossless.